# Why capturing lambda does not capture variables?

Tags: c++, lambda

I don't understand why the callback lambda passed to `c_style_callback` does not access to the correct values of `callback` and `key`. How to get these 2 to be available from the lambda?

I tried with explicit copy `[callback=callback, key=key]`, didn't help.

This is a C++ wrapper implementation of a C method called `subscribe`.

I think the following code covers my issue, let me know if anything else needed.

Wrapper, the issue is located here. Please check the comments at the end of the lines:

```
std::function<void()> AWS::subscribe(const std::string &topic, std::function<void(const std::string&)> callback, QoS qos) {
  ESP_LOGI(TAG, "subscribe: %s", topic.c_str());

  std::string key("Test...");

  auto task = c_style_callback(
    [=] (AWS_IoT_Client *pClient, char *topicName, uint16_t topicNameLen, IoT_Publish_Message_Params *params) {
      std::string json;
      json.assign((char *)params->payload, (size_t)params->payloadLen);
      ESP_LOGI(TAG, "subscribe cb payload=%s", json.c_str()); // works
      ESP_LOGI(TAG, "key '%s'", key.c_str()); // undefined behaviour
      callback(json);// error, exit
    }
  );

  m_error = ::aws_iot_mqtt_subscribe(
    &m_client,
    key.c_str(),
    key.length(),
    qos,
    task.get_callback<AWS_IoT_Client*, char*, uint16_t, IoT_Publish_Message_Params*>(),
    task.get_pvoid()
  );

  if (m_error != SUCCESS) {
    ESP_LOGD(TAG, "subscribe: error=%d", m_error);
    return nullptr;
  }

  return [=] () {
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "unsubscribe %s", key.c_str());  // works
    callback(key); // works
  };
} // subscribe
```

`c_style_callback` utility function:

```
template<class F>
struct c_style_callback_t {
  F f;
  template<class...Args>
  static void(*get_callback())(Args..., void*) {
    return [](Args...args, void* fptr)->void {
      (*static_cast<F*>(fptr))(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    };
  }
  void* get_pvoid() {
    return std::addressof(f);
  }
};

template<class F>
c_style_callback_t< std::decay_t<F> >
c_style_callback( F&& f ) { return {std::forward<F>(f)}; }
```

Main task where the `subscribe` wrapper is being called - this is only for giving context to the example, how I try to use the C++ wrapper of `subscribe`:

```
{
...
aws->subscribe(
  topic,
  [] (const std::string &json) -> void {
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "got json: %s", json.c_str());
  }
);
...
}
```

**Update:**

More about `aws_iot_mqtt_subscribe`:

```
/**
 * @brief Subscribe to an MQTT topic.
 *
 * Called to send a subscribe message to the broker requesting a subscription
 * to an MQTT topic.
 * @note Call is blocking.  The call returns after the receipt of the SUBACK control packet.
 *
 * @param pClient Reference to the IoT Client
 * @param pTopicName Topic Name to publish to
 * @param topicNameLen Length of the topic name
 * @param pApplicationHandler_t Reference to the handler function for this subscription
 * @param pApplicationHandlerData Data to be passed as argument to the application handler callback
 *
 * @return An IoT Error Type defining successful/failed subscription
 */
IoT_Error_t aws_iot_mqtt_subscribe(AWS_IoT_Client *pClient, const char *pTopicName, uint16_t topicNameLen,
                                QoS qos, pApplicationHandler_t pApplicationHandler, void *pApplicationHandlerData);
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I'm quite unexperienced in C++. I have learnt a lot recently but still there are lot left to know. I'm sorry for asking something that may be straightforward to you but would be really appreciated if you helped me a little. Thanks.

Comment: For lambda captures, I've gotten into the habit of being explicit for each one, and avoid capture defaults.  Probably because I'm paranoid.  That may be a useful technique in this situation.

Comment: I have tried capturing by reference as well as value. Both way ended up crash.

Comment: @haxpanel `[&]` means capture all variables by reference, `[=]` means capture all variables by value. After C++14 you can make explicit copy `[json=json]`. Read docs on lambda, it is not complicated

Comment: @Slava I'm aware of this. *Not the explicit copy. I'm going to try it.

Comment: If you aware why you posting code with capturing by reference? You need to post [mcve] with capturing by value and only then we can help you. And you should not guess and randomly change statements but debug and find were is the culprit.

Comment: @Slava Where did you see capturing by reference?

Comment: @haxpanel Seeing a default capture by reference inside main, but not capturing anything at all. Why did you provide the default then? Is there anything important hidden in the ESP_LOGI or TAG macros?

Comment: @Aconcagua I got rid of the unnecessary logic for the example but accidentally left the `&`. Trying to give context to the issue by showing how I try to call the wrapper. Please look at the wrapper `AWS::subscribe()` instead.

Comment: As you do not provide [mcve] and have `[&]` for lambda I can assume you do need to capture something. I cannot check if capturing is required (and not willing either), it is your responsibility to remove irrelevant details from your code.

Comment: @Slava I have removed that `&` and yes, you're right I need to capture something in that lambda as well. The issue I'm fighting at the moment is not there, it is inside the `AWS::subscribe` wrapper class method. I'd be happy to provide you anything to understand the problem.

Comment: What's `aws_iot_mqtt_subscribe`, and what does it do with its arguments? Dos it store them somewhere for latter use? Note that the pointer returned by `task.get_pvoid()` points to a member of `task`, and `task` is a local variable. When `subscribe` returns, `task` is destroyed and that pointer becomes dangling. The lambda you passed to `c_style_callback` is destroyed together with `task`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I have updated the question. `aws_iot_mqtt_subscribe` pushes its  arguments into an array, it is a pubsub mechanism. It calls the `callbacks` with matching topic on new event. Yes that seems to be a local variable but I'm not sure how it works, how to protect it. I was thinking of using unique or shared pointers but don't know if that'd solve the problem.

Comment: *"I'm not sure how it works"* That's simple - it doesn't; that's why you are here asking this question. Your program exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an object after its lifetime has ended.

Comment: Is this entire approach wrong? My ultimate goal is to have a nice C++ interface of that C implementation where modern callbacks can be used, don't have to pollute higher level logic with low level `aws_iot_mqtt_*` related "blocks".

Comment: Your callback needs state. You need to somehow ensure that state actually lives for as long as the callback remains registered and may be called. No amount of wrapping lambdas into other lambdas would extend the lifetime.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I was thinking of returning a function called `unsubscribe` (which you can see there is a rudimentary version already there), inside that function I'd store the state of the lambda there. The a variable in main references to the `unsubscribe` which holds a reference to the `task`. Not sure this makes sense.. If so what's your opinion?

Answer (score 3):

I assume `aws_iot_mqtt_subscribe` stores its arguments for latter reference - to call, in response to some event at some later point in time, the function passed as its next-to-last argument, with the pointer passed as its last argument.

The pointer obtained with `task.get_pvoid()` points to a data member of `task`. In turn, `task` is a local variable - it's destroyed when `subscribe` returns, together with its data member, whereupon that pointer becomes dangling.

Later, the function manufactured by `c_style_callback_t::get_callback` receives that no-longer-valid pointer and attempts to dereference it. Thereby the program exhibits undefined behavior, by way of accessing an object after its lifetime has ended.

Comment: Thank you, well described. Is there a solution for this? Is the whole approach wrong? Using `unique_pointer` would help? Or shall I keep track of the tasks by adding them into a `vector` for instance?

Comment: @haxpanel you need to store your task object somewhere so it isn't destroyed

Comment: @AlanBirtles Great, I'm going to try it.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I attempted to store it in a static vector: `static std::vector<decltype(task)> vec;

  vec.push_back(task);`. No luck.

Comment: What did you pass to `aws_iot_mqtt_subscribe` - `task.get_pvoid()` or `vec.back().get_pvoid()`? The former still points into a local variable; it's the latter that points into an element of the vector, which is a copy of that local variable. But even that ain't gonna work very well - as you add more elements to the vector, it will eventually have to reallocate its storage, which will invalidate all pointers to its elements. Ultimately, you want to allocate `task` on the heap.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks, I see. Can you please give me some hints on how would you allocate `task` on the heap?

Comment: With `new` or `std::make_unique`.